# Optimizing a date conversion loop

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a set of data (n), about 1500 items long filled with dates in DD.MM.YYYY format that excel does not regognize.  My goal is to change them to something that excel can work with, this is how I do it.

```
Function date_to_excel()
Call public_dims

Dim date_i As String
date_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Range(Cells(7, 5), Cells(7 + n, 5))

For i = 0 To n
date_i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Cells(7 + i, 5)
    If date_i <> "" Then
    date_array = Split(date_i, ".")
    date_i = date_array(1) & "/" & date_array(0) & "/" & date_array(2)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Cells(7 + i, 5) = date_i
    End If
Next

End Function
```

The function works allright, but it just takes a really long time.  **What I am askingfrom the community is for ideas on how to optimize this loop.**  I have tried adding the entire range with the dates into an Array and looking through that, but it doesn't seem compatible with my method of changing the date format (the date_i = line near the end).

Comment: Perhaps you can just do a `Replace`. Find the `.` and replace with `/`.

Comment: If you format the cells as 'Custom' and set the custom format as 'dd.mm.yyyy', Excel will then recognize the values in the cells as date

Comment: @Zac no way. Not working

Comment: Are the days and month s always on 2 char (01..11), or variable  (1..11)?

Comment: Sorry, that is my bad. I tried date in the cell with '/' and it worked but if its with '.' it doesn't work. Please scrap my comment

Comment: @iDevelop they are always on 2 chars.

Comment: user @BrakNicku provided the most convinient solution, I encourage users to have a look a it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Text To Columns functionality with DMY column format.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Range("E7:E" & 7 + n).TextToColumns _
                                DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
```

Comment: simplest and fastest

Comment: Super simple solution, works quick and does the job - thank you, I will use it many time over in the future!

Answer (score 0):

"I have tried adding the entire range with the dates into an Array and looking through that"...

Yes, that is the way to go. Reading and writing to cells on the sheet one at a time is what is taking a lot of time.

```
Dim vData as Variant
Dim vDates() as Date
ReDim vDates(1 to n, 1 to 1) as Date
Dim i as Long

vData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Range("E7").Resize(n,1).Value

For i = 1 to n
    vDates(i,1) = DateSerial(Split(vData(i,1),".")(2),vData(i,1),".")(1),vData(i,1),".")(0))
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spread").Range("E7").Resize(n,1).Value = vDates
```

Comment: The OP had an empty string check in his code but good work +1.