# Changing what content is displayed in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, format, cell

small problem here.  I have an application in which date time data is displayed as a string in European format.  I did up a quick VBA script to convert it into a standard Americas format, intending to change it into a DateTime value.  Instead, once I got the format changed over, Excel did that for me automatically.  So far, so good.  Only problem is, it's only displaying the date, even though when I click on the cell it shows the date AND time as a value.  For example, the cell displays the value 6/8/2017, but the value listed in the formula bar is 6/8/2017  12:56:07 PM.

While this is technically good enough for my application, I want the full value to be listed in the cell.  I know this can probably be done by changing Excel's properties, I'm a little leary of depending on the user to have Excel configured just right.  What I'd like to know if there's a way in VBA to tell the cell, or column, to display the complete value.

Also, I don't trust the Excel "automatic" features, just in case someone hasn't set up their Excel in the same way I have.  Any way to override these?

Comment: Record a macro while setting the cell format to your required display - you can then incorporate that into your code.

Comment: In VBA, you can use the cells' `NumberFormat` property to set how to display the value (it sounds like you want a `"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` format).  Obviously, it may be easier to just do the same thing via Excel's Format Cells option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` followed by the `NumberFormat` property of your selected cell. If you post your code, it would be easier to provide a suggestion, but without it here is an example of what you can try.

```
Sub changeDateFormat()
'
' changeDateFormat Macro
' Assuming the initial active cell (e.g., "A1") is a text of a date
     Range("A1").Activate

    While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(RC[-1]) + TIMEVALUE(RC[-1])"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yy h:mm;@"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large range to convert, this hack using `TextToColumns` is *very* efficient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371934/78522